# points diamond tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to set 10 points on the right side of a diamond with tikz and it does not give a good result. Would there be a better approach to specifying points on a geometric shape?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{environ}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{losange} = [diamond, draw, text badly centered, inner sep=1cm]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [losange] (L) {Losange};
\node [above = 0.1mm of L] (s1) {S1};
\node [below right= 1mm of s1] (s2) {S2};
\node [below right= 1mm of s2] (s3) {S3};
\node [below right= 1mm of s3] (s4) {S4};
\node [below right= 5.5mm of s4] (s5) {S5};
\node [below left= 1mm of s5] (s6) {S6};
\node [below left= 1mm of s6] (s7) {S7};
\node [below left= 1mm of s7] (s8) {S8};
\node [below left= 1mm of s8] (s9) {S8};
\node [below left= 1mm of s9] (s10) {S9};
\node [below left= 1mm of s10] (s11) {S10};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Some `append after command` tricks may be useful here:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\tikzset{create marks/.style={
  append after command={
    \pgfextra{\let\savednode=\tikzlastnode}%
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in {0,.2,...,1}{ 
      ($(\savednode.north)!\i!(\savednode.east)$) 
      coordinate (\savednode-\j) }
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 6] in {0,.2,...,1}{ 
      ($(\savednode.east)!\i!(\savednode.south)$) 
      coordinate (\savednode-\j) }}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw=red, shape=diamond, minimum size=3cm, create marks] (A) {A};
\foreach \i in {1,...,11}
  \fill [fill=red] (A-\i) circle [radius=.05] node [right] {\i};
\node [draw=blue, shape=diamond, minimum size=4cm, create marks] 
  at (0, 4) (B) {B};
\foreach \i in {1,...,11}
  \fill [fill=blue] (B-\i) circle [radius=.05] node [right] {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

like this?

[image]

node are not equidistant but code is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{losange} = [diamond, draw, text badly centered, inner sep=1cm]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [losange] (L) {Losange};
\foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {90,72,...,-90}
 \node [right=1mm] at (L.\i) {S\j};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shape have angle anchors, i.e. you can write `L.0` (same as `L.east`) or `L.15` to get an anchor which is the intersection of a line from the center of a node in the angle given and the border.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{environ}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{losange} = [diamond, draw, text badly centered, inner sep=1cm]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [losange] (L) {Losange};
\node [anchor=south west] (s1)  at (L.90) {S1};
\node [anchor=south west] (s2)  at (L.75) {S2};
% for illustration
\draw [blue] (L.center) -- ++(55:3cm) node[right] {$55^\circ$ (L.55)};
\fill [red] (L.55) circle (0.1);
%
\node [anchor=south west] (s3)  at (L.55) {S3};
\node [anchor=south west] (s4)  at (L.35) {S4};
\node [anchor=south west] (s5)  at (L.15) {S5};
\node [anchor=west]       (s6)  at (L.0)  {S6};
\node [anchor=north west] (s7)  at (L.-15) {S7};
\node [anchor=north west] (s8)  at (L.-35) {S8};
\node [anchor=north west] (s9)  at (L.-55) {S9};
\node [anchor=north west] (s10) at (L.-75) {S10};
\node [anchor=north west] (s11) at (L.-90) {S11};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \node [rectangle] (R) {Rectangle};
\node [anchor=south east] (r1)  at (R.90) {R1};
\node [anchor=south east] (r2)  at (R.75) {R2};

Comment: Suppose I want to add four rectangles east south west north that I can write text inside.\node [rectangle] (R) {Rectangle};
\node [anchor=south east] (r1)  at (R.90) {R1};
\node [anchor=south east] (r2)  at (R.75) {R2};

Comment: @HoudaAraj it's not clear what you want, but this may help: `\node [draw,rectangle,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=4cm] (R) {Rectangle};
\node [draw=green,anchor=north] (r1) at (R.south) {R1};
\node [draw=green,anchor=west]  (r2) at (R.east)  {R2};
\node [draw=green,anchor=south] (r3) at (R.north) {R3};
\node [draw=green,anchor=east]  (r4) at (R.west)  {R4};
\node [draw=blue,anchor=south] (r5) at (R.south) {R5};
\node [draw=blue,anchor=east]  (r6) at (R.east)  {R6};
\node [draw=blue,anchor=north] (r7) at (R.north) {R7};
\node [draw=blue,anchor=west]  (r8) at (R.west)  {R8};`

Comment: Thanks@Mike\node [draw,rectangle,fill=blue!10, rounded corners,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=5cm, anchor=north] (r1) at (L.south) {R1}; 
\node [draw,rectangle,fill=blue!10, rounded corners,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=5cm, anchor=west] (r2) at (L.east) {R2}; 
\node [draw,rectangle,fill=blue!10, rounded corners,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=5cm, anchor=south] (r3) at (L.north) {R3}; 
\node [draw,rectangle,fill=blue!10, rounded corners,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=5cm,anchor=east] (r4) at (L.west) {R4}; How to put some space between the diamond and the rectangles.

Comment: @HoudaAraj there are many ways to do this. One way is to add the option `below=1cm` to node `r1`, `right=1cm` to `r2`, `above=1cm` to `r3`, and `left=1cm` to `r4`.

Comment: \node [anchor=south east] (l1)  at (L.90) {L1};
\node [anchor=south east] (l2)  at (L.75) {L2};
\node [anchor=south east] (l3)  at (L.55) {L3};
\node [anchor=south east] (l4)  at (L.35) {L4};
\node [anchor=south east] (l5)  at (L.15) {L5};
\node [anchor=east]       (l6)  at (L.180)  {L6};
\node [anchor=north east] (l7)  at (L.-15) {L7};
\node [anchor=north east] (l8)  at (L.-35) {L8};
\node [anchor=north east] (l9)  at (L.-55) {L9};
\node [anchor=north east] (l10) at (L.-75) {L10};
\node [anchor=north east] (l11) at (L.-90) {L11};

Comment: ,Now,I tried to specify point on the other side of the diamond, good for L1,L6 and L11.\node [anchor=south east] (l1) at (L.90) {L1};\node [anchor=south east] (l2) at (L.75) {L2};\node anchor=south east] (l3) at (L.55) {L3};\node [anchor=south east](l4)  at (L.35) {L4};\node [anchor=south east] (l5) at (L.15){L5};\node [anchor=east] (l6)  at (L.180) {L6};\node anchor=north east] (l7) at (L.-15) {L7};\node [anchor=north east] (l8)  at (L.-35) {L8};\node [anchor=north east] (l9) at (L.-55) {L9};\node anchor=north east] (l10) at (L.-75) {L10};\node [anchor=north east] (l11) at (L.-90) {L11};

Comment: @HoudaAraj for getting nodes on the left side you can use for example `\node [anchor=south east] (l3) at (L.125) {L3};`. To get it further away, you can use `\node [anchor=south east,above left=5mm] (l3a) at (L.125) {L3};`. Further, I recommend reading up on nodes in the PGF/TikZ manual (for version 3.0.1a), especially sections 17.5 Positioning Nodes, 67.2 Predefined Shapes, and 67.3 Geometric Shapes.